# How to pass ViewModel with enumerable props to controller in asp.net core mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to insert a product to database which has some related entities through one form in ASP .NET Core MVC project.
My View Model contains enumerable properties as per each related entity.

View Model:

```
public class ProductSingleViewModel
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string CoverImageUrl { get; set; }
    public int ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public int ProductDiscount { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public bool ShowInHomePage { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductColorsViewModel> ProductColor { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductFeaturesSetViewModel> ProductFeature { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductGuaranteeViewModel> ProductGuarantee { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductImage> ProductImage { get; set; }
}
```

IEnumerable fieds needs to be filled by user before sending to controller.
For each enumerable field I have a table in db which relates field with product same as below one:

```
public partial class ProductFeature
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int FeatureId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsTop { get; set; }

    public virtual Feature Feature { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Create.cshtml View :

```
<form asp-action="Create" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- left column -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- general form elements -->
                <div class="box box-primary">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Product Details</h3>
                    </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                    <!-- form start -->
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="CategoryId" class="control-label">Category</label>
                            <select asp-for="CategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CategoryId"></select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Serial" class="control-label">Serial</label>
                            <input asp-for="Serial" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Serial" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label">Title</label>
                            <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Subtitle" class="control-label">Subtitle</label>
                            <input asp-for="Subtitle" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Subtitle" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Summary" class="control-label">Summary</label>
                            <input asp-for="Summary" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Summary" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="CoverImageUrl" class="control-label">Cover Image</label>
                            <input asp-for="CoverImageUrl" type="file" Class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="CoverImageUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="ProductPrice" class="control-label">Price</label>
                            <input asp-for="ProductPrice" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ProductPrice" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="ProductDiscount" class="control-label">Discount</label>
                            <input asp-for="ProductDiscount" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="ProductDiscount" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label asp-for="Stock" class="control-label">Stock</label>
                            <input asp-for="Stock" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Stock" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input asp-for="ShowInHomePage" /> Show In Home Page
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input asp-for="IsActive" /> Active
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" /> |
                            <a asp-action="Dashboard_ProductsList" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="box box-primary">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Features</h3>
                    </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Images</label>
                            <input type="file" multiple id="ProductImage" name="ProductImage" Class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" style="display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Select Guarantees</label>
                            <hr />
                            @foreach (var guarantee in (List<OnlineStore.Models.Entities.Guarantee>)ViewData["Guarantees"])
                            {
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="minimal" id="@guarantee.Id"> @guarantee.Title
                                </label>
                            }
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" style="display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Select Colors</label>
                            <hr />
                            @foreach (var color in (List<OnlineStore.Models.Entities.Color>)ViewData["Colors"])
                            {
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="minimal" id="@color.Id"> @color.DisplayTitle
                                </label>
                            }
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" style="display: block; margin-bottom: 10px;">Select Features</label>
                            <hr />
                            @foreach (var feature in (List<OnlineStore.Models.ViewModels.ProductFeaturesSetViewModel>)ViewData["Features"])
                            {
                                <div class="featuresSetHead" style="padding: 4px; background-color: #eee; color: #021c5a;">@feature.ProductFeaturesHead</div>

                                foreach (var featureDeatails in feature.FeatureDetails)
                                {
                                    <div class="row" style="margin: 5px 0;">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label class="control-label">@featureDeatails.ProductFeatureTitle</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="@featureDeatails.ProductFeatureId" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                }
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Description</h3>
                </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Create Action:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewData["CategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.Category, "Id", "DisplayTitle");
    ViewData["Colors"] = _context.Color.ToList();
    ViewData["Features"] = _productFeaturesRepository.GetProductFeatures(); ;
    ViewData["Guarantees"] = _context.Guarantee.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

And Create Action with ViewModel parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ProductSingleViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Model passed to controller has enumerable props with 0 counts.

[image]

The question is how to bind related enumerable entities while passing View Model to controller?

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to properly work you need to use in your views the `for` loop instead of `foreach` one.

An example would be this loop:

```
@foreach (var guarantee in (List<OnlineStore.Models.Entities.Guarantee>)ViewData["Guarantees"])
{
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="minimal" id="@guarantee.Id"> @guarantee.Title
    </label>
}
```

Change it to:

```
@{ var guaranteesList = List<OnlineStore.Models.Entities.Guarantee>)ViewData["Guarantees"]); }
@for (int i = 0; i < guaranteesList.Count; i++)
{
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="minimal" asp-for="@guaranteesList[i].Id"> @guaranteesList[i].Title
    </label>
}
```

A recommendation would be to pass a model to the view on the get method containing directly a list of objects. This will simplify things instead of using `ViewData`.